# How to add text inside the doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me with the below js code?
I want to add text to the doughnut chart like the below image link.

[image: Chart]

```
var a = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myChart1 = new Chart(a, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    labels: ["Approved", "Declined"],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: ["#8DE08D", "rgb(233,122,122)"],
        data: [55, 49]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you add the tag(s) of whatever system you are using (chartjs?).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/4rk1ucgx/

here you can see that at `line 45`  `var text = "75%",` of the code you can add whatever text you would like inside the doughnut chart